# show the data one by one while ajax running in background

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to show a search query data from ajax page where data retrieve from there and append it to a div if the result is found. Instead of have all the data at a time i want to show it one by one.

i can show it at a time but don't know how to show it one by one.

suppose when i run the query and found 1000 record and i only want name to display in main page instead of store it in an array and display it how can i show one by one while the ajax running in background

Comment: Chances are that your PHP page that does the search query is using mysqli_query(), correct?

Comment: yes and i can have all the data in a array and return to page where i can show the data. but how can i show data one by one.

Comment: Do you want to show one at a time for a visual effect or to increase performance?

Comment: By one by one do you mean display one record, wait X second, display other record, wait X second and like that? or do you mean `(record A)` <line break> `(record B)`?

Comment: (record A) <line break> (record B)

Comment: OK. I have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
//call $.ajax here
}, 5000); /
```

You could use this function for calling ajax function with interval , the 5000 here is 5000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

To display the record like this, you do your ajax call which returns your array, then you can foreach to print each result:

```
//Your AJAX call
$.ajax(){
     //Blank string
     String rows = "";

     //When the query is complete and ready
     if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){

         //Foreach result in the array that is returned
         this.responseText.foreach(function (item){
             //Append the result to the string
             Rows + <tr> + item + '</tr>';
         })

         //Put the results in the table
         document.getElementById('resultsTable').innerHTML = Rows;
     }
}
```

add a table to your page with the ID of "resultsTable"

```
<table id="resultsTable">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your php return a json array to the ajax call and then in the success function implement a loop to display each result in a new div